# Using Trig Substitution for calculating the Electric Field with 3 variables in the denominator

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-fields

I am reading how to calculate the Electric field for an infinite plane of charge that happens to be in the xy plane. The equation sets up as

$$E =  \frac{\sigma }{4\pi \varepsilon  }\int_{-\infty }^{\infty} \frac{dx'dy'}{[z^{2} + x'^{2} + y'^{2}]^{3/2}}$$

However the example is the Using the following trig substitution for the denominator:

$$\int \frac{dx}{(a^{2} + x^{2})}$$

I am not understanding why this is the case. I am assuming since the charge is in the xy plane and the point is on the z axis, z is being treated as a constant and can be taken as a within the trig sub. But I am not clear on how to use it in this form with x,y, and z in the denominator. Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you do multiple integrals: one at a time, treating every other variable as a constant. So, if you want to do the $x'$ integral first, then $y'$ and $z$ are constant. So, what happens if I say $a^2 = y'^2 + z^2$?